# Xamarin Studio Android Emulator Extremely Slow

Tags: xamarin, android-emulator

I am using Macbook Pro 2015.  I installed Xamarin Studio and Android SDK

[image]

I created AVD like this

[image]

When I start my AVD, it never moves further than screen showing "android" on it, even 1/2 hour after starting it

[image]

adb devices command shows:

```
adb devices

List of devices attached

emulator-5554   device
```

Is there something I am doing wrong in setting my emulator.  I am aware that android emulators are slow but it wasn't this slow.  I am also aware of HAXM but I found instruction to install them bit to flaky and I dont want to take a risk.  I also know about Genimotion but that is not an option for me.

Is there another way to speed up the android emulator?

Comment: Using Intel's HAXM is the only way to run x86-based AVM Images on macOS and Windows. Without HAXM, the only other real option is Genymotion as it is VirtualBox-based.

Comment: Please show the `logcat` output.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I used an alternative solution to fix this problem.

1. Install VMware or VirtualBox
2. Download the ISO file of your android platform http://www.android-x86.org/download
3. Create a virtual machine with the ISO file

You can use these settings:

- Target OS: Choose Linux
- Target Os version: Other
- 1 GB RAM
- Add a new hard drive: VDI drive, dynamically sized
- Start the VM

Now you can connect Xamarin to the VM.

4. Find the path to your Android sdk-platform-tools
5. Open a terminal in your Host and locate sdk-platform-tools and type ./adb connect

Now you can run your code from Xamarin to the virtual machine, which is really fast compared to simulation from Xamarin.

Comment: Thanks, I actually did not have to do any of this and my emulators are quite fast now.  I don't remember if I changed anything though

Answer (score 0):

make sure that Android version of your Target Framework is the same of smaller than Android version of your emulator you have chosen to build.